# Set properties on labels using for statement in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying something that I don't know if it is possible to do.

When I press a button, the property .visible of many labels must change, and I am doing that using this:

```
Private Sub AlakranPositionsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AlakranPositionsButton.Click
    If AlakranLabel.Visible = False Then
        Label4.Visible = True
        Label5.Visible = True
        AlakranLabel.Visible = True
        Alakran1Label.Visible = True
        Alakran2Label.Visible = True
        Alakran3Label.Visible = True
        Alakran4Label.Visible = True
        Alakran5Label.Visible = True
        Alakran6Label.Visible = True
        Alakran7Label.Visible = True
        Alakran8Label.Visible = True
        Alakran9Label.Visible = True
        Alakran10Label.Visible = True
        Alakran1YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran2YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran3YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran4YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran5YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran6YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran7YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran8YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran9YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran10YTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran1XTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran2XTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran3XTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran4XTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran5XTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran6XTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran7XTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran8XTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran9XTextBox.Visible = True
        Alakran10XTextBox.Visible = True
    Else
        Label4.Visible = False
        Label5.Visible = False
        AlakranLabel.Visible = False
        Alakran1Label.Visible = False
        Alakran2Label.Visible = False
        Alakran3Label.Visible = False
        Alakran4Label.Visible = False
        Alakran5Label.Visible = False
        Alakran6Label.Visible = False
        Alakran7Label.Visible = False
        Alakran8Label.Visible = False
        Alakran9Label.Visible = False
        Alakran10Label.Visible = False
        Alakran1YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran2YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran3YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran4YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran5YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran6YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran7YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran8YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran9YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran10YTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran1XTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran2XTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran3XTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran4XTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran5XTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran6XTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran7XTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran8XTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran9XTextBox.Visible = False
        Alakran10XTextBox.Visible = False
    End If
```

I think that there must be a way to do something like this:

```
If AlakranLabel.Visible = False Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To 20
            Label(i).visible = False
        Next
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To 20
            Label(i).visible = True
        Next
    End If
```

Someone knows how to do this? I am not able to see how to do it..

Thanks!

***Solution***
Declaration of the lists:

```
Dim listObjectiveLabels As List(Of Label) = New List(Of Label)
Dim listObjectiveTextBox As List(Of TextBox) = New List(Of TextBox)
```

Add each label and textbox in a list:

```
listAlakranLabels.Add(AlakranLabel)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran1Label)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran2Label)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran3Label)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran4Label)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran5Label)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran6Label)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran7Label)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran8Label)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran9Label)
    listAlakranLabels.Add(Alakran10Label)

    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran1YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran2YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran3YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran4YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran5YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran6YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran7YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran8YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran9YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran10YTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran1XTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran2XTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran3XTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran4XTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran5XTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran6XTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran7XTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran8XTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran9XTextBox)
    listAlakranTextBox.Add(Alakran10XTextBox)
```

Use for each sentence:

```
For Each l As Label In listAlakranLabels
            l.Visible = True
        Next
        For Each l As TextBox In listAlakranTextBox
            l.Visible = True
        Next
```

Comment: Surely all of these controls are somehow logically connected and belong together.  Grouped in, say, a panel or groupbox.  Or better yet, a UserControl so you can hoist a lot of code into another class.  So just set that panel's Visible property.

Comment: @HansPassant most practical answer, really. Here's hoping he did group them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got 2 options:

1.- Adding your labels to a `List<Label>` and the use a `For Each` to set their `Visible` property:

```
Dim allLabels As List(Of Label) = New List(Of Label);

    allLabels.Add(Label4)
    allLabels.Add(Label5)
    allLabels.Add(AlakranLabel)
    ...

    For Each l As Label In allLabels
        l.Visible = True
    Next
```

2.- If you want to show/hide all the labels inside a container, you can `For Each` the container `Controls` Collection, like this:

```
    For Each l As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
        l.Visible = True
    Next
```

**EDIT**

You've got another option, using the `Find` method of the `Controls` collection:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Me.Controls.Find("Alakran" & i & "Label", False).FirstOrDefault().Visible = True
Next
```

This would set all labels from `Alakran1Label` to `Alakran10Label` visibility to True

Comment: This one, the first method you mention, is what I've done and works perfectly. I'm going to edit my answer with the solution. Thanks Pikoh!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on all instances of the `Label` or `Textbox` in your form (or container) by :

1. First declaring a control variable to handle each object in your Container collection
2. Determine if the current control is a label
3. setting their visibility to false.

   ```
   Dim lbl_holder as Control

   For each lbl_holder in Me.Controls

      If typeof lbl_holder is Label or Typeof lbl_holder is Textbox then
         lbl_holder.Visible = False
      End If

   Next
   ```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote answers that have helped you and to accept one that you have found most useful